# Key/Value Postgres Sql Table Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am currently building a Rails app where there is a "documents" data table that stores references to pdfs living on an S3 server. These documents could have 100 different types. Each type can have up to 20 attributes or meta info.

My dilemma is do I make 100 relational tables for every doc type or just create one key/value data table with a reference to the doc_id.

My gut tells me to go key/value for flexibility for searching and supporting more and more document types over time without having to create new migrations. However, I know there are pitfalls with this technique. My first concern of course is the size of the table. The key/value table could end up with millions of rows.

On the other hand, having 100 attribute tables would be  nightmare to query against in a full text search situation.

So bottom line is, by going with key/value, is performance on a 3 column Postgres table with potentially millions of rows a scaling problem? Also what about joins on the value field?

This data would almost never change by the way. So it would be 90% reads.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a single table with an hstore column. It is a PostgreSQL data type designed for storing key/value pairs.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

There are also multiple Ruby gems that add hstore support to ActiveRecord. Here is one that I wrote: https://github.com/JackC/surus You can search ruby gems for about a dozen more alternatives as well.

Comment: Thanks Jack, this is EXACTLY the functionally I need.